# url rewrite to an external url

Tags: url-rewriting

I am trying to use URL Rewrite and Application Request Routing to rewrite to an external URL.  I have set up the following rule:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="RewriteExternal" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="patternToMatch/(.*)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="http://100.100.100.100/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" logRewrittenUrl="false" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

In the rule, "patternToMatch" is the pattern I am trying to match, and the 100.100.100.100 server is the external server (outside our firewall) to which I am trying to rewrite.  I have turned on logging and see that the pattern is matching, the URL is rewritten approropriately, but then I see "ARR_WEBFARM_NOT_ROUTED" with the 100.100.100.100 IP address.  The request is then rewritten back to the orignal request and the request fails.

I understand that for internal redirects that I could add the internal server to the web farm, but this doesn't apply to external servers.  Is it possible to rewrite to external servers?  If so, how do I get around using the web farm and avoid the "ARR_WEBFARM_NOT_ROUTED" error?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4):

FYI I know this is old but here's my two cents: **ARR_WEBFARM_NOT_ROUTED** may be a "false positive" as in my case I had two local IIS sites with identical rules for reverse proxy one worked and one did not.  BOTH sites had the ARR_WEBFARM_NOT_ROUTED entry, I assume, because neither had any actual web farm entries, just the external sites (though the sites I was rewriting to were also local IIS sites).

In addition OP said "rewritten back", and that was ALSO in both my working and non-working sites logs, which mean it may not be a smoking gun either.

Turns out my problem was actually a conflict between ARR and MVC.  I would have thought ARR was higher in the pipeline before MVC, but somehow MVC butts in and will try to route the original pre-rewritten URL thus causing 404's.  I'm not sure of the exact cause but one fix was to tell MVC to ignore the rewrite URL's (either in global.asax.cs or RouteConfig.cs):

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("rewrite_path_here/{*pathInfo}");
```

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: Spot on. I had the same problem and it was indeed MVC intercepting the rewritten URL and serving a 404! Added the ignore and its working now. How come though, the URL rewrite rule is at a server level, so it should never get to a site level to evaluate this surely?
Thanks again for posting this though, sorted my issue

Comment: Note, this did help me out, but if you are using MVC areas then you must ensure that this is done in the RegisterArea() method and not in RouteConfig's RegisterRoutes() method:           

`public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
 context.Routes.IgnoreRoute("blog/{*pathInfo}");
 ...
}`

Comment: This helped me finally sort out a URL rewrite in Umbraco